# Maximum size of data types specific to a system

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out the minimum and maximum values for C data types like short, int and long.

I found minimum sizes in a wikipedia article, but I have no idea how to find the maximum for my computer.

I have a mac osx 10.8.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `{TYPE}_[MIN|MAX]` macros defined in [`limits.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) to check type range:

```
printf("range of short int: %d - %d", SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX);
```

You can use `sizeof` operator, to check type size:

```
printf("size of short int: %zu", sizeof(short int));
```

#### EDIT:

Also check @JoachimPileborg answer as he has provided a better reference for limits.

Comment: `sizeof` returns a value of type `size_t`, for which you should use `%zu` and not `%d`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze You're absolutley right, I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Do you know why printf("range of long int: %i - %i\n", LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX); gives me range of long int: 0 - -1

Comment: @papercuts Use `%ld` for `long` and `%lu` for `unsigned long`. `%i` is for `int`.

Comment: oh okay thanks! that's helpful

Answer (score 6):

Use the macros in the header files [`<stdint.h>`, `<limits.h>` and `<float.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

Answer (score 1):

The header [limit.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) will be your friend here. You need the values SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX, INT_MIN, INT_MAX, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX from it. Their names are self-descriptive I believe.

Answer (score 1):

To have limits include the following

```
#include <limits.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the constant defined in limit.h and float.h :

(Quick search on internet for the list)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/